# Windows 7 Registry for Java Runtime points to absent file

Tags: jvm, registry, client

My java programs stopped working today after an upgrade and started giving error: Failed to load shared library, library name: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
 I checked and there is no 'client' directory at this location. There is a 'server' directory that has a jvm.dll.
 There was no mention of this path in any configuration file and finally I ended up looking into registry and there under 
JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment/1.7 are four keys. Variable 'RuntimeLib' has this value.
 Obviously the dll does not exist at this location. I have reinstalled JRE and again there is no file at this location. 
I tried to rename the 'server' folder to 'client' filder but the program gave a different error. 'Unable to find the start class'. So Apparently the jvm in server folder is not the one expected in client folder.
 It is a complete 64 bit environment.

Am I the only one who has seen this issue?
 Does JRE install create a 'client' folder for you gurs on Windows 7?
 Any suggestions?

Thanks